# How to setup terraform cicd with gcp and github actions in a multidirectory repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, github-actions

### Introduction

I have a repository with all the infrastructure defined using IaC, separated in folders. For instance, all terraform configuration is in `/terraform/`. I want to apply all terraform files inside that directory from the CI/CD.

### Configuration

The used github action is shown below:

```yaml
name: 'Terraform'

on: [push]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'      
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        #working-directory: terraform

    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    # Install the latest version of Terraform CLI and configure the Terraform CLI configuration file with a Terraform Cloud user API token
    - name: Setup Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      

    - id: 'auth'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}'

    - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1'

    # Initialize a new or existing Terraform working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
    - name: Terraform Init
      run: terraform init

    # Checks that all Terraform configuration files adhere to a canonical format
    - name: Terraform Format
      run: terraform fmt -check

      # On push to "master", build or change infrastructure according to Terraform configuration files
      # Note: It is recommended to set up a required "strict" status check in your repository for "Terraform Cloud". See the documentation on "strict" required status checks for more information: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/types-of-required-status-checks
    - name: Terraform Apply
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false
```

### Problem

If I log in and then change directory to apply terraform it doesn't find to log in.

```
storage.NewClient() failed: dialing: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

On the other hand, if I don't change the directory then it doesn't find the configuration files as expected.

```
Error: No configuration files
```

Tried to move the terraform configuration files to the root of the repository and works. How could I implement it in a multidirectory repository?

Comment: it looks like that google auth action looks for a credentials file at a known path at the time it runs. So I assume if you were in my_dir and ran the action, the creds file and environment variable are set to look in my_dir. Perhaps when you change the directory to look at terraform their code can no longer find the credentials. Maybe read thru their code or echo out some environment variables or ls some files to gather more info. https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth/blob/main/src/main.ts#L197

does it work if you cd into /terraform, auth, then run terraform? should do...

Answer (score 0):

Such feature was requested [before](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth/issues/134). As explained in the issue, auth files is named as follows `gha-creds-*.json`.

Therefore, added a step just before using terraform to update the variable environment and moving the file itself:

```
    - name: 'Setup google auth in multidirectory repo'
      run: |  
        echo "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/terraform/`ls -1 $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS | xargs basename`" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        mv $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/gha-creds-*.json $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/terraform/
```